# how to generate and store UUDI for a device in loopback an

Tags: node.js, loopbackjs, loopback

I want to make a web service to generate UUID and store it with Loopback in a table something like

> http://localhost:3000/api/getuudi

The functions for token and uuid are working fine but I dont know where should I had to place for example uuid to get token and store in table

```
 function generateUUID() {
      var d = new Date().getTime();
      if(window.performance && typeof window.performance.now === "function"){
          d += performance.now();; //use high-precision timer if available
      }
      var uuid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx7xxxyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
          var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
          d = Math.floor(d/16);
          return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
      });
    return uuid;
};
```

Token

```
  function generateToken() {
      var d = new Date().getTime();
      if(window.performance && typeof window.performance.now === "function"){
          d += performance.now();; //use high-precision timer if available
      }
      var uuid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx9xxxyxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function(c) {
          var r = (d + Math.random()*16)%16 | 0;
          d = Math.floor(d/16);
          return (c=='x' ? r : (r&0x3|0x8)).toString(16);
      });
    return uuid;
};
```

UUDI.json

```
  "name": "UUDI",
  "plural": "getuudi",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
    "validateUpsert": true
  },
  "properties": {
    "uuid": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "date": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "time": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can generate uuid using loopback functional properties.

Check - https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#properties